# Styling the tab menu - Android

Tags: android

I am newer to Android development and am having a hard time figuring out how to style the different tabs.  When I created the project in Eclipse, I picked to have the tab/slider navigation and I am trying to figure out how to edit the styles of those through `XML`

Suggestions and thoughts?

David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this can be achieved using 
    TabHost
    TabWidget
    TabHost.TabSpec
    FrameLayout &
    Intent.

[Here](http://mrbool.com/how-to-customize-tab-layout-in-android/28153) you can get step by step tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need the TabHost itself, a TabSpec , an Indicator for the spec, and a selector to change tab icon based on state, have a look [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/08/android-tab-layout-tutorial/)